# TS2305: Module '"ra-core"' has no exported member 'Pagination'. #72 when i try to do a webpack build

Tags: reactjs, react-admin, webpack-5

in reactadmin based project, All of a sudden I am getting this error after adding Webpack build with Typescript transpilation.

```
ERROR in src/ra-data-django-rest-framework/src/index.ts:4:3
TS2305: Module '"ra-core"' has no exported member 'Pagination'.
    2 | import {
    3 |   Identifier,
  > 4 |   Pagination,
      |   ^^^^^^^^^^
    5 |   Sort,
    6 |   Filter,
    7 |   fetchUtils,

ERROR in src/ra-data-django-rest-framework/src/index.ts:5:3
TS2305: Module '"ra-core"' has no exported member 'Sort'.
    3 |   Identifier,
    4 |   Pagination,
  > 5 |   Sort,
      |   ^^^^
    6 |   Filter,
    7 |   fetchUtils,
    8 |   DataProvider,

ERROR in src/ra-data-django-rest-framework/src/index.ts:6:3
TS2305: Module '"ra-core"' has no exported member 'Filter'.
    4 |   Pagination,
    5 |   Sort,
  > 6 |   Filter,
      |   ^^^^^^
    7 |   fetchUtils,
    8 |   DataProvider,
    9 | } from 'ra-core';

ERROR in src/RaDataDRFDataProvider.ts:4:3
TS2305: Module '"ra-core"' has no exported member 'Pagination'.
    2 | import {
    3 |   Identifier,
  > 4 |   Pagination,
      |   ^^^^^^^^^^
    5 |   Sort,
    6 |   Filter,
    7 |   fetchUtils,

ERROR in src/RaDataDRFDataProvider.ts:5:3
TS2305: Module '"ra-core"' has no exported member 'Sort'.
    3 |   Identifier,
    4 |   Pagination,
  > 5 |   Sort,
      |   ^^^^
    6 |   Filter,
    7 |   fetchUtils,
    8 |   DataProvider,

ERROR in src/RaDataDRFDataProvider.ts:6:3
TS2305: Module '"ra-core"' has no exported member 'Filter'.
    4 |   Pagination,
    5 |   Sort,
  > 6 |   Filter,
      |   ^^^^^^
    7 |   fetchUtils,
    8 |   DataProvider,
    9 | } from 'ra-core';
```

#### Package.json

```
{
  "name": "djrauth-ra-clientv2",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.2",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.20.2",
    "@mui/styles": "^5.6.2",
    "@sentry/react": "^7.17.4",
    "@sentry/tracing": "^7.17.4",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.1.1",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "axios": "^0.26.1",
    "babel-loader": "^9.1.0",
    "css-loader": "^6.7.1",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.3",
    "patch-package": "^6.4.7",
    "ra-data-django-rest-framework": "^0.2.1",
    "ra-data-fakerest": "^4.0.1",
    "ra-data-simple-rest": "^4.0.2",
    "ra-in-memory-jwt": "^1.0.0",
    "ra-input-rich-text": "^4.2.0",
    "react": "^18.0.0",
    "react-admin": "^4.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^18.0.0",
    "react-google-recaptcha-v3": "^1.10.0",
    "react-icons": "^4.4.0",
    "react-loading": "^2.0.3",
    "react-query-devtools": "^2.6.3",
    "react-redux": "^8.0.2",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "sass": "^1.56.1",
    "sass-loader": "^13.2.0",
    "svg-url-loader": "^8.0.0",
    "ts-loader": "^9.4.1",
    "typescript": "^4.8.4",
    "typescript-loader": "^1.1.3",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4",
    "webpack": "^5.75.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.10.0",
    "webpack-merge": "^5.8.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "postinstall": "patch-package",
    "dev": "webpack  serve --mode=development    --config  webpack.config.dev.js",
    "prod": "webpack      --mode=production     --config  webpack.config.prod.js"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.18.6",
    "file-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.5.0",
    "style-loader": "^3.3.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^4.11.1"
  },
  "homepage": ".",
  "proxy": "http://localhost:80"
}
```

#### tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    /* Visit https://aka.ms/tsconfig to read more about this file */
    /* Projects */
    // "incremental": true,                              /* Save .tsbuildinfo files to allow for incremental compilation of projects. */
    // "composite": true,                                /* Enable constraints that allow a TypeScript project to be used with project references. */
    // "tsBuildInfoFile": "./.tsbuildinfo",              /* Specify the path to .tsbuildinfo incremental compilation file. */
    // "disableSourceOfProjectReferenceRedirect": true,  /* Disable preferring source files instead of declaration files when referencing composite projects. */
    // "disableSolutionSearching": true,                 /* Opt a project out of multi-project reference checking when editing. */
    // "disableReferencedProjectLoad": true,             /* Reduce the number of projects loaded automatically by TypeScript. */
    /* Language and Environment */
    "target": "es2016", /* Set the JavaScript language version for emitted JavaScript and include compatible library declarations. */
    // "lib": [],                                        /* Specify a set of bundled library declaration files that describe the target runtime environment. */
    // "jsx": "preserve",                                /* Specify what JSX code is generated. */
    // "experimentalDecorators": true,                   /* Enable experimental support for TC39 stage 2 draft decorators. */
    // "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,                    /* Emit design-type metadata for decorated declarations in source files. */
    // "jsxFactory": "",                                 /* Specify the JSX factory function used when targeting React JSX emit, e.g. 'React.createElement' or 'h'. */
    // "jsxFragmentFactory": "",                         /* Specify the JSX Fragment reference used for fragments when targeting React JSX emit e.g. 'React.Fragment' or 'Fragment'. */
    // "jsxImportSource": "",                            /* Specify module specifier used to import the JSX factory functions when using 'jsx: react-jsx*'. */
    // "reactNamespace": "",                             /* Specify the object invoked for 'createElement'. This only applies when targeting 'react' JSX emit. */
    // "noLib": true,                                    /* Disable including any library files, including the default lib.d.ts. */
    // "useDefineForClassFields": true,                  /* Emit ECMAScript-standard-compliant class fields. */
    // "moduleDetection": "auto",                        /* Control what method is used to detect module-format JS files. */
    /* Modules */
    "module": "commonjs", /* Specify what module code is generated. */
    // "rootDir": "./",                                  /* Specify the root folder within your source files. */
    // "moduleResolution": "node",                       /* Specify how TypeScript looks up a file from a given module specifier. */
    // "baseUrl": "./",                                  /* Specify the base directory to resolve non-relative module names. */
    // "paths": {},                                      /* Specify a set of entries that re-map imports to additional lookup locations. */
    // "rootDirs": [],                                   /* Allow multiple folders to be treated as one when resolving modules. */
    // "typeRoots": [],                                  /* Specify multiple folders that act like './node_modules/@types'. */
    // "types": [],                                      /* Specify type package names to be included without being referenced in a source file. */
    // "allowUmdGlobalAccess": true,                     /* Allow accessing UMD globals from modules. */
    // "moduleSuffixes": [],                             /* List of file name suffixes to search when resolving a module. */
    // "resolveJsonModule": true,                        /* Enable importing .json files. */
    // "noResolve": true,                                /* Disallow 'import's, 'require's or '<reference>'s from expanding the number of files TypeScript should add to a project. */
    /* JavaScript Support */
    // "allowJs": true,                                  /* Allow JavaScript files to be a part of your program. Use the 'checkJS' option to get errors from these files. */
    // "checkJs": true,                                  /* Enable error reporting in type-checked JavaScript files. */
    // "maxNodeModuleJsDepth": 1,                        /* Specify the maximum folder depth used for checking JavaScript files from 'node_modules'. Only applicable with 'allowJs'. */
    /* Emit */
    // "declaration": true,                              /* Generate .d.ts files from TypeScript and JavaScript files in your project. */
    // "declarationMap": true,                           /* Create sourcemaps for d.ts files. */
    // "emitDeclarationOnly": true,                      /* Only output d.ts files and not JavaScript files. */
    // "sourceMap": true,                                /* Create source map files for emitted JavaScript files. */
    // "outFile": "./",                                  /* Specify a file that bundles all outputs into one JavaScript file. If 'declaration' is true, also designates a file that bundles all .d.ts output. */
    // "outDir": "./",                                   /* Specify an output folder for all emitted files. */
    // "removeComments": true,                           /* Disable emitting comments. */
    // "noEmit": true,                                   /* Disable emitting files from a compilation. */
    // "importHelpers": true,                            /* Allow importing helper functions from tslib once per project, instead of including them per-file. */
    // "importsNotUsedAsValues": "remove",               /* Specify emit/checking behavior for imports that are only used for types. */
    // "downlevelIteration": true,                       /* Emit more compliant, but verbose and less performant JavaScript for iteration. */
    // "sourceRoot": "",                                 /* Specify the root path for debuggers to find the reference source code. */
    // "mapRoot": "",                                    /* Specify the location where debugger should locate map files instead of generated locations. */
    // "inlineSourceMap": true,                          /* Include sourcemap files inside the emitted JavaScript. */
    // "inlineSources": true,                            /* Include source code in the sourcemaps inside the emitted JavaScript. */
    // "emitBOM": true,                                  /* Emit a UTF-8 Byte Order Mark (BOM) in the beginning of output files. */
    // "newLine": "crlf",                                /* Set the newline character for emitting files. */
    // "stripInternal": true,                            /* Disable emitting declarations that have '@internal' in their JSDoc comments. */
    // "noEmitHelpers": true,                            /* Disable generating custom helper functions like '__extends' in compiled output. */
    // "noEmitOnError": true,                            /* Disable emitting files if any type checking errors are reported. */
    // "preserveConstEnums": true,                       /* Disable erasing 'const enum' declarations in generated code. */
    // "declarationDir": "./",                           /* Specify the output directory for generated declaration files. */
    // "preserveValueImports": true,                     /* Preserve unused imported values in the JavaScript output that would otherwise be removed. */
    /* Interop Constraints */
    // "isolatedModules": true,                          /* Ensure that each file can be safely transpiled without relying on other imports. */
    // "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,             /* Allow 'import x from y' when a module doesn't have a default export. */
    "esModuleInterop": true, /* Emit additional JavaScript to ease support for importing CommonJS modules. This enables 'allowSyntheticDefaultImports' for type compatibility. */
    // "preserveSymlinks": true,                         /* Disable resolving symlinks to their realpath. This correlates to the same flag in node. */
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true, /* Ensure that casing is correct in imports. */
    /* Type Checking */
    "strict": true, /* Enable all strict type-checking options. */
    // "noImplicitAny": true,                            /* Enable error reporting for expressions and declarations with an implied 'any' type. */
    // "strictNullChecks": true,                         /* When type checking, take into account 'null' and 'undefined'. */
    // "strictFunctionTypes": true,                      /* When assigning functions, check to ensure parameters and the return values are subtype-compatible. */
    // "strictBindCallApply": true,                      /* Check that the arguments for 'bind', 'call', and 'apply' methods match the original function. */
    // "strictPropertyInitialization": true,             /* Check for class properties that are declared but not set in the constructor. */
    // "noImplicitThis": true,                           /* Enable error reporting when 'this' is given the type 'any'. */
    // "useUnknownInCatchVariables": true,               /* Default catch clause variables as 'unknown' instead of 'any'. */
    // "alwaysStrict": true,                             /* Ensure 'use strict' is always emitted. */
    // "noUnusedLocals": true,                           /* Enable error reporting when local variables aren't read. */
    // "noUnusedParameters": true,                       /* Raise an error when a function parameter isn't read. */
    // "exactOptionalPropertyTypes": true,               /* Interpret optional property types as written, rather than adding 'undefined'. */
    // "noImplicitReturns": true,                        /* Enable error reporting for codepaths that do not explicitly return in a function. */
    // "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,               /* Enable error reporting for fallthrough cases in switch statements. */
    // "noUncheckedIndexedAccess": true,                 /* Add 'undefined' to a type when accessed using an index. */
    // "noImplicitOverride": true,                       /* Ensure overriding members in derived classes are marked with an override modifier. */
    // "noPropertyAccessFromIndexSignature": true,       /* Enforces using indexed accessors for keys declared using an indexed type. */
    // "allowUnusedLabels": true,                        /* Disable error reporting for unused labels. */
    // "allowUnreachableCode": true,                     /* Disable error reporting for unreachable code. */
    /* Completeness */
    // "skipDefaultLibCheck": true,                      /* Skip type checking .d.ts files that are included with TypeScript. */
    "skipLibCheck": true, /* Skip type checking all .d.ts files. */
  }
}
```

#### Webpack build is in 3 parts

1. webpack common
2. webpack dev
3. weback prod

#### Webpack.config.common.js

```
const path = require("path");
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  entry: "./src/index.js",
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, "/dist"),
    filename: "bundle.js",
  },
  performance: {
    hints: false,
    maxEntrypointSize: 512000,
    maxAssetSize: 512000,
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
        {
            test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            use: {
              loader: 'babel-loader'
            }
        },
        {
            test: /\.(gif|svg|jpg|png|webp)$/,
            loader: "file-loader",
        },        
        {
            test: /\.ts$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            use: [
              {
                loader: 'ts-loader',
                options: {
                  transpileOnly: true
                }
              }
            ]
        },
        {
            test: /\.svg$/,
            use: [
            {
                loader: "svg-url-loader",
                options: {
                limit: 10000,
                },
            },
            ],
        },
        {
            test: /\.s?css$/,
            use: [
              "style-loader", 
              "css-loader", 
              "sass-loader"
            ],
        },
    ],
  },
  resolve: {
    modules: ["node_modules"],
    extensions: [".ts", ".tsx", ".js", "jsx", "json"],
  },
  target: ["web", "es5"],
  
  plugins: [new HtmlWebpackPlugin()],

};
```

#### Webpack DEv

```
const path = require("path");
const { merge } = require("webpack-merge");
const common = require("./webpack.config.common.js");
module.exports = merge(common, {
  mode: "development",
  devtool: "cheap-source-map",
  devServer: {
    static: {
      directory: path.join(__dirname, "public"),
    },
    historyApiFallback: true,
  },
});
```

#### Webpack prod

```
const { merge } = require("webpack-merge");
const common = require("./webpack.config.common.js");
module.exports = merge(common, {
  mode: "production",
});
```

Comment: React-admin made no change recently on these components. Do you have a lockfile? Or did you upgrade a dependency?

Comment: Only addition i did is Added TS Config, and added webpack build. I dont get what u mean as lockfile.

Comment: I mean packages-lock.json or yarn.lock